# After Windows 10 upgrade, how do you view the status of your RAID array?

Tags: windows-10, raid, intel-rst

So I have a Windows-7 machine with RAID-1 array (Intel RAID-Controller provided by motherboard "Intel ICH10R").

With Windows-7, I used to check the RAID array by starting "[Intel Matrix Storage Console](https://www.google.com/search?q=intel+matrix+storage#safe=off&q=intel+matrix+storage+site:intel.com)" [version 8.9.x (from the year 2009)](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/55005/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-) GUI.

I upgraded the machine to windows-10. After the Windows 10 upgrade, I can't check the status of the RAID array anymore.

The Intel GUI shows an error message:

[image]

**After Windows 10 upgrade, how do you view the status of your RAID array?**

If there is a command line method that returns with simple string status that would be acceptable too (i.e. the command would return "your array is good" or "your array is degraded with x drive failure" or "your array is rebuilding [and is x percent complete]").

I did happen to notice in Device Manager a driver for the RAID was changed on the same date as Windows 10 was installed:

[image]

Comment: !VERY IMPORTANT! The "09/13/2016" is where I tried to do something and FAILED. Here's what I tried:: uninstall of Intel Matrix Storage v8.9 (older 2009 program) --> reboot --> install Intel Rapid Storage v14.x (newer 2015 program) --> reboot --> windows failed to boot. I was very lucky and had a system restore point. I used the system restore point which removed the newer program and added back the older program (and I think also reverted any drivers). So after that debacle I am back to square one... no way to check my RAID array from Windows.

Comment: Why not just install the new version *without* removing the old version?

Comment: I'll give that a try. First I have to find some time for that.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the only way I can think of is to reboot the machine. During the boot hit the keyboard shortcut to enter the RAID Controller's screen (the RAID controller screen is after the BIOS but before the operating system (windows-10 in this case)).

Comment: I saw [an article from Intel about upgrading from Intel Storage Matrix to the newer Intel Rapid Storage](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/technologies/000005711.html). I don't have the time/energy/patience to try that right now. I did a "uninstall Intel-Storage --> reboot --> install Intel-Rapid --> reboot". The article differs slightly in not recommending an uninstall of Intel-Storage: "install Intel-Rapid --> reboot".